# Can someone explain why this react component is not outputting the images or the correct key prop?

Tags: reactjs, prop, array.prototype.map

The PNG images are locally saved on my machine and imported into this React component. They are not loading on the page. I am also getting a key prop error. The key prop solution was working when I was pulling from a normal Rest API. It stopped working when I tried to refer to my own array. The image src is showing "[Object Object]" instead of the image source as I would expect.

```js
import React from 'react';
import basketball from '../img/basketball.png';
import bike from '../img/bike.png';
import boxing from '../img/boxing.png';

function ExerciseIcons() {
  return (
    [
      {
        name: "bike",
        id: "1",
        image: <img src={bike} />
      },
      {
        name: "basketball",
        id: "2",
        image: {basketball}
      },
      {
        name: "boxing",
        id: "3",
        image: {boxing}
      },
    ].map(item => (
      <ul>
        <li key={item.id}> <img src={item.image} /></li>
      </ul>
    ))
  )
}

export default ExerciseIcons;
```

[Here is what the output looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QQRG.png)

Comment: are you using Webpack by chance? Webpack either looks for a 'public' or I believe 'assets' directory to properly load images. It won't recognize your /img/ directory unless you've modified the webpack config to point there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array has some problems. `basketball` and `boxing` have `{}` around them which is object syntax. So the value of the `image` key is actually something like `{ basketball: basketball }`. This is why its showing "[Object Object]". `bike` is a complete JSX element, not an image source.

You'll need to change it to this:

```js
[
  {
    name: "bike",
    id: "1",
    image: bike
  },
  {
    name: "basketball",
    id: "2",
    image: basketball
  },
  {
    name: "boxing",
    id: "3",
    image: boxing
 },
]
```

**Remember:** `{}` within JSX is syntax for evaluating JavaScript expressions. Outside of JSX, this is object notation.

The issue with the `key` is that you are providing it to the wrong element. The key must be provided to the *root* element inside the mapping function. I this case that is the `ul` (although I wonder if this is actually what you want, it will make a new list for every item).